# BizTalk custom pipeline component - Read a JSON node value and promote properties

Tags: c#, biztalk, biztalk-2016

In my BizTalk receive port I receive JSON from a web service. I want to read the particular JSON node value(comma separated value) in custom pipeline component and promote the property for the message if the node value has the expected value.
For example :

Json Node in message

```
"Dept": "support, Development,Test"
```

So I want read the JSON node `Dept` and if it has value `Development` then I need to promote a property for the message say `devDept` is `true` otherwise `false`.
I have an idea how it can be done using orchestration. But I want to do this in custom pipeline component. Can any one share the idea or help on this?

Comment: Hi Navaneet.  Did any of the answers below help you?  Did you manage to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

There are few approaches to do this:

1. You can use [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) JSON library to read JSON and then promote the property. You can add this to your project using Nuget packages. And then you would need to deploy the assembly in packages folder to GAC.
2. Alternatively, You can also use BizTalk [JSON decoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/processing-json-messages-using-biztalk-server) pipeline component to convert JSON to XML and then use XmlReceive pipeline to promote properties without any use of orchestration.

Both approaches are fine, depends on other processing you are doing with JSON. Deployment wise approach 2 is better as you don't have to deploy Newtonsoft Json library to GAC

Comment: The problem isn't the JSON decoding, it is promoting the property based on a comma separated value

Comment: Sorry, missed that part. In that case approach 1 will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

As Vikas has said, you will first want to use a JSON Decoder.

To actually promote a property depending on what is in a list of values comma separated, I would use the [BRE Pipeline Framework](https://github.com/mbrimble/brepipelineframework/), this allows you to execute Business Rules in Policies in a pipeline, rather than having to execute it in the Orchestration.   You would just have a rule that would look at that element and if it contains Development, then create the promoted property.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to SDK samples how to implement custom pipeline component for promoting a value of XPath expression under given name:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2013 R2\SDK\Samples\Pipelines\ArbitraryXPathPropertyHandler"
```

Using this component you can evaluate and promote to specified property name any expressions like

```
//*[local-name()='Dept' and contains(text(), 'Development')]
```